# Running Theano with GPU on windows, python 2.7, cuda 7.5

Tags: theano, theano-cuda

I have been running Theano without GPU on py 2.7 for quite some time now. Then decided to check out GPU support. So followed all steps given in here:
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#abstract

Then opened the device query sln in msvc 2013 and built it (as mentioned in the above link to check if installation was successful). On run it gives me an error (attached screen shot).

[image]

A similar error comes up when I run the starter program with gpu in py 2.7 with Theanorc file contents:

```
[global]
device = gpu1
floatX = float32
nocleanup = True
[cuda] 
root = /usr/local/cuda-7.5
[nvcc]
fastmath = True
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\cl.exe
```

received no errors for nvcc -V, and cl.exe.
OS - win7 SP1
NVIDIA GeForce GT650M

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got similar error when my video card driver mismatched with the CUDA Toolkit.

Make sure you are using video driver included in CUDA installer. If you are not sure, reinstall latest CUDA Toolkit installer and update your video driver with it.

Comment: Thanks.

Actually re-installing gpu latest driver solved the issue.
My computer -> device manager -> update driver
(Phew! Windows installation of gpu support almost took my sleep away)

Finally able to get 10x+ gains on simple computations. 

Heartening!
Been a while since I played around with optimizing fft codes in assembly.